# how to dropping a column name using the sqlite query in the table in ios5.1

Tags: ios, ios5, sqlite

First I used this query but it's not working:

```
ALTER TABLE a DROP COLUMN y
```

and later I use this query

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1_backup(a,b); 
INSERT INTO t1_backup SELECT a,b FROM t1; 
DROP TABLE t1;
CREATE TABLE t1(a,b); 
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT a,b FROM t1_backup; 
DROP TABLE t1_backup;
COMMIT;
```

it also is not working so please give any idea how to write query for dropping a column in sqlite using iOS.

Comment: Certainly the `ALTER` syntax is not supported. See [`ALTER TABLE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). Regarding the second variation not working, what error are you getting from `sqlite3_errmsg`?

Comment: The latter queries don't have anything obviously incorrect (though the field names and table names changed from the first query). You could probably make this latter set of queries more efficient (e.g. create table t1_backup, copy t1 data, remove t1, rename t1_backup to t1 with `ALTER TABLE` command ... this saves you a copy of table), but I don't see any syntactical errors in your sql statements here. It will be interesting to see what `sqlite3_errmsg` says.